# WCF WSHttpBinding SOAP Security Negotiation Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, wcf

I've got a fairly simple WCF self-hosted service using the WSHttpBinding that just refuses to work. If service and client runs on the same machine there's no problem, but as soon as I move the service to the window-server 2008 the client fails the communication attempts with

> EXCEPTION
>
> [System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException] {"SOAP security negotiation with 'http://hvw-svr-01/SIT' for target 'http://hvw-svr-01/SIT' failed. See inner exception for more details."}
>
> INNER EXCEPTION
>
> [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception] {"The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed. The server may not be running in an account with identity 'host/hvw-svr-01'. If the server is running in a service account (Network Service for example), specify the account's ServicePrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for the server. If the server is running in a user account, specify the account's UserPrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for the server."}

Since it's a self-hosted service I suppose I need to specify the UserPrincipalName, but no matter what I try for that property it just won't work.

- domain\username
- domain@username
- host/localhost
- host/hvw-svr-01
- ... and so on

Tried it with different user accounts aswell, including the built-in Administrator. If I try BasicHttpBinding instead of WSHttpBinding everything works as expected. I read tons of articles about that problem on google (and stackoverflow) but I still cannot figure what the problem is and how to specify that identity.

Edit: Service App.Config

```
   <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
     <service name="SIT.Communication.Gate">
        <host>
           <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:2323/SIT" />
           </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SIT.Core.IGate">
           <identity>
              <dns value="localhost"/>
              <userPrincipalName value="XZDom\DGrain"/>
           </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

Edit: The Client itself is basically just this code fragment

> ```
>         ChannelFactory<IGate> sitFactory = new ChannelFactory<IGate>(new WSHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://hvw-svr-01:2323/SIT"));
>         IGate sitProxy = sitFactory.CreateChannel();
>         bool pong = sitProxy.Ping(); <------ throws exception
> ```

Comment: Can you post the configuration you used to host the service?

Comment: If you remove `idenity` section altogether from your config, does it work?

Comment: Nope does not work, already tried that (read somewhere on stackoverflow)

Comment: are the machines in the same domain?

Comment: also can you post the client's config so we can see what the client is expecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable the Negotiate process to select the Kerberos protocol for network authentication, the client application must provide an SPN, a user principal name (UPN), or a NetBIOS account name as the target name. If the client application does not provide a target name, the Negotiate process cannot use the Kerberos protocol. If the Negotiate process cannot use the Kerberos protocol, the Negotiate process selects the NTLM protocol.

In cross-domain, kerberos has to be used. Since service is running as local system account, a SPN identity has to be used on the client side for the target name.

For more informaiton, read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929650

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you that helped alot indeed. But why is my case exactly cross-domain? The self-hosted WCF app runs under an account that is member of our domain (the windows-server & client machine aswell). I tried providing a UPN at client configuration and it indeed worked, so that was definately the problem... but why do I have to do this? I would expect WCF to provide the UPN of the currently logged in user account per default if no one is provided.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I have a similar problem. For some reason calling the WCF service using IP address allows NTLM and authentication succeeds. Using fully qualified domain name authentication fails with a "soap security negotation failed...etc" because I am not supply the UPN (I don't know how by config because the endpoint is an issuer endpoint in a federation scenario, and I can't see how to add the UPN to the issuer binding config)

Comment: @naacl - did you ever get enlightened on this topic?  I'm struggling to understand my all-same-domain user account situation myself

Comment: Oh, well I just realized for myself that my DNS host name was not correct.  The host was reachable by the hostname I was using, but its default name, the one it presents itself as, was different.  Using that correct one allowed me to skip the explicit spn business.

Answer (score 3):

You can opt for basic HTTP binding if `WSHttpBinding` is not an actual requisite. :)

Basic HTTP eliminates the `<identiy>` tag so UPN and SPN problems wouldn't occur.

Comment: How do I opt for basic HTTP binding?

Comment: Hi,by replacing your binding wsHttpBinding by a basicHttpBinding                         on client side and by exposing an endpoint with basicHttpBinding on service side

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I tried almost all the settings in web.config and in the IIS server. 
And the best way for me is to set UPN when creating the client:

```
EndpointAddress endptAddress = 
               new EndpointAddress(
                  new Uri(your URL),
                  EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("domain\username"));
```