# UPN Identity for SOAP call getting switched in a clustered service

Tags: wcf, soap, windows-authentication

I make a call in which the WCF service client is constructed like so:

```
var endpointIdentity = EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("DOMAINNAME\serviceAccountName@DOMAINNAME");
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(theServiceUri, endpointIdentity);
var serviceClient = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_Service", endpointAddress);
```

The binding looks like this:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="WSHttpBinding_Service"
           closeTimeout="02:00:00"
           openTimeout="02:00:00"
           receiveTimeout="02:00:00"
           sendTimeout="02:00:00"
           bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
           transactionFlow="false"
           hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
           maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
           messageEncoding="Text"
           textEncoding="utf-8"
           useDefaultWebProxy="true"
           allowCookies="false">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                  maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                  maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                  maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    <reliableSession ordered="true"
                     inactivityTimeout="02:00:00"
                     enabled="false" />
    <security mode="Message">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

This code is running in a clustered service. When `serviceClient` calls one of its methods, I'm getting this error:

> SOAP security negotiation with `'http://host-name:PORT/EndpointName'` for target `'http://host-name:PORT/EndpointName'` failed. See inner exception for more details. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) authentication failed. The server may not be running in an account with identity **'host/host-name'**. If the server is running in a service account (Network Service for example), specify the account's ServicePrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for the server. If the server is running in a user account, specify the account's UserPrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for the server.

Please note: the identity being used for the SOAP call is the host name (emphasized above), not `DOMAINNAME\serviceAccount` like it should, and like it does when I run through the debugger. What settings might be off on the server to cause this?

I checked the `wsdl` the service is publishing, and the `wsdl:service` block looks how I would expect:

```
<wsdl:service name="Service">
    <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_Service" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_Service">
        <soap12:address location="http://localhost:PORT/EndpointName"/>
        <wsa10:EndpointReference>
            <wsa10:Address>http://localhost:PORT/EndpointName</wsa10:Address>
            <Identity xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity">
                <Upn>serviceAccount@DOMAINNAME</Upn>
            </Identity>
        </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092688/wcf-wshttpbinding-soap-security-negotiation-failed

Comment: @vibhu Thanks, but both the client and server are within our local network, so the call is not cross-domain and we do not need or want to use kerberos. NTLM should be working, as far as I know.